# Allign collapsible button to the right of navbar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-4

I would like to have the collapsible button alligned to the right of the navbar (Bootstrap v4). I've tried to wrap the button in:

```
<div class='nav navbar-nav navbar-right'>
```

And also added the `float-xs-right` class... without success.

I have created the following plunker:

https://plnkr.co/edit/AeUbHyXL34G2VdQKpEpo?p=preview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`float-xs-right` was introduced in Bootstrap Alpha 5, but the plunker CSS is referencing Bootstrap Alpha 4. It works fine with Alpha 5:

http://www.codeply.com/go/Ina8YfuXaU

Comment: Great catch between Alpha 4 and 5. But just applying `float-xs-right` on the toggle button makes the content below wrap incorrectly. The float would have to be cleared by wrapping the floated elements inside a parent with class `clearfix`. http://www.bootply.com/HzCVuqiFc1

Answer (score 0):

maybe add position absolute or fixed and move it to right

```
.navbar .navbar-toggler{
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}
```

you also want to move collapsible content out of `nav`

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Brand</a>
      <button class="navbar-toggler float-xs-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar" aria-controls="exCollapsingNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">Expand</button>
    </nav>

    <div class="collapse" id="exCollapsingNavbar">
      <div class="bg-inverse text-muted p-1">
        <h4>Collapsed content</h4>
        <span class="text-muted">Toggleable via the navbar brand.</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

see updated [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/uzttOoHopQdo1bKje8jd?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

simply fix with `text-align:right`

```
.navbar {
  text-align:right;
}
```

try with this snippet

```css
.navbar {
  text-align:right;
}
#exCollapsingNavbar {
  text-align:left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Bootstrap, from Twitter</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"/>
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge"/>
    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css" data-semver="4.0.0-alpha.4" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link data-require="bootstrap@*" data-semver="4.0.5" rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/css/bootstrap-flex.min.css" integrity="sha384-AysaV+vQoT3kOAXZkl02PThvDr8HYKPZhNT5h/CXfBThSRXQ6jW5DO2ekP5ViFdi" />
    
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="3.0.0" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap" data-semver="4.0.5" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-light bg-faded">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">My Brand</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler float-xs-right" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#exCollapsingNavbar" aria-controls="exCollapsingNavbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">Expand</button>
  <div class="collapse" id="exCollapsingNavbar">
    <div class="bg-inverse text-muted p-1">
      <h4>Collapsed content</h4>
      <span class="text-muted">Toggleable via the navbar brand.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
    
  </body>

</html>
```